# Never ending loop while loading HTML in Web View

Tags: swift, uiwebview, navigationbar

I try to load webView with existing website.

I added buttons on a navigation bar which have url links:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webView.delegate = self


    var myHTMLString = ""
    guard let myURL = URL(string: domainURLString) else {
        print("Error: \(domainURLString) doesn't seem to be a valid URL")
        return
    }

    do {
        myHTMLString = try String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .utf8)
    } catch let error {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
    webView.frame = view.bounds
    webView.scalesPageToFit = true

    createBottomNavigationBar()


    webView.loadHTMLString(myHTMLString as String, baseURL: nil)

}




func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    print("===============================start===============================")

    let myURLString:String = (request.url?.absoluteString)!

    var myHTMLString = ""

    if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.linkClicked {
        print("link clicked")

        webView.stopLoading()

        var myHTMLString = ""
        let myURL = URL(string: myURLString)
        do {
            myHTMLString = try String(contentsOf: myURL!, encoding: .utf8)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
            return true
        }

        webView.loadHTMLString(myHTMLString as String, baseURL: nil)

        print("first")
        print(request.url)


    }else if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.other){
        print("This is for Navigation Button click")
        //webView.loadHTMLString(myHTMLString as String, baseURL: nil)
    }
    else{
        print("else")
    }
    return true
```

However, When I uncomment

```
webView.loadHTMLString(myHTMLString as String, baseURL: nil)
```

in this statement:

```
}else if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.other){
```

the app loops forever.

The statement is for when one of the navigation buttons click fires. It redirects to internal url like "http://yahoo.com/mail".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the expected behaviour based on your code. The line

```
webView.loadHTMLString(myHTMLString as String, baseURL: nil)
```

in `viewDidLoad` will try to load the HTML. This in turn will call the delegate method

```
webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
```

Inside the delegate method, when your code hits the `else if` case, it will again call

```
webView.loadHTMLString(myHTMLString as String, baseURL: nil)
```

which in turn will call the delegate method again. It's a cyclical loop. The code is working as it should. You need to change the logic.